# Switch chrome tabs and refresh every 5 seconds - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension using the Chrome tabs API that will cycle through all of the open tabs in a window and refresh each one every n seconds. I'm having trouble iterating my for loop once every 5 seconds. I've tried a few different ways of setting timeouts and such but I'm either ending up with the loop not running at all, or I get an infinite loop. I'm new to javascript. Any help would be appreciated!

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var foundSelected = false;
      (function switch() {
        for(i = 0; i <= tabs.length; i++){
          if(i == tabs.length){
            i = 0;
          }
          if (tabs[i].active){
            foundSelected = true;
          }
            // Finding the next tab    
          else if (foundSelected){
            // Selecting the next tab.
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {active: true});
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[i].id);
            setTimeout(switch, 5000);
          }
        }
      })();


    // var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {

      chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});
    }
  }
);
```

I realize that there are already extensions out there that do this. I'm creating my own as a learning experience and for more control over functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Create background.js like given below. I thnik it will work properly.

background.js

```
/* Below code start background.js when you start your browser
 * and sw function work after every 5 second and reload every tab. 
 */
function sw()
{
   chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true},function(tabs){
     var i=0;
     console.log(tabs.length);
     for(i=0;i<=tabs.length;i++)
     {
         chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[i].id);
     }

   })
};
setInterval(sw,5000);
```

Comment: I have done some changes in above code and now it is working fine in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  setInterval(function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      var foundSelected = false;
      for(var i = 0; i <= tabs.length; i++){
        if(i == tabs.length){
          i = 0;
        }
        if (tabs[i].active){
          foundSelected = true;
        }
        // Finding the next tab.
        else if (foundSelected){
          // Selecting the next tab.
          chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {active: true});
          chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[i].id);
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  }, 5000);

});
```